# Вывести данные в одну строку и указать названия столбцов из значения строки

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть скрипт:

```
SELECT * FROM payments 
where payment_id = '57095'
```

Результат вывода:

```
row_id  payment_id  _name   _value
90120   57095   account     7077017
90122   57095   brand       ACT
90121   57095   location    MST
90123   57095   payMethod   PAA
90124   57095   rtt         021456668
```

Каким образом можно изменить select, чтобы результатом стала такая структура?

```
row_id  payment_id  account brand location  payMethod rtt   
90120   57095    7077017     ACT    MST      PAA       021456668
```

Comment: [FROM — использование PIVOT и UNPIVOT](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующий метод.

SQL Server 2005 и новее.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (row_id  INT, payment_id  INT, _name VARCHAR(30),   _value VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @tbl (row_id, payment_id, _name, _value) VALUES
(90120, 57095, 'account', '7077017'),
(90122, 57095, 'brand', 'ACT'),
(90121, 57095, 'location', 'MST'),
(90123, 57095, 'payMethod', 'PAA'),
(90124, 57095, 'rtt', '021456668');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @payment_id INT = 57095;

SELECT row_id = (SELECT TOP(1) row_id FROM @tbl WHERE payment_id = @payment_id ORDER BY row_id)
    , payment_id
    , MAX(CASE WHEN _name = 'account' THEN _value ELSE '' END) [account]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN _name = 'brand' THEN _value ELSE '' END) [brand]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN _name = 'location' THEN _value ELSE '' END) [location]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN _name = 'payMethod' THEN _value ELSE '' END) [payMethod]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN _name = 'rtt' THEN _value ELSE '' END) [rtt]
FROM @tbl
WHERE payment_id = @payment_id
GROUP BY payment_id;
```

**Output**

```
+--------+------------+---------+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| row_id | payment_id | account | brand | location | payMethod |    rtt    |
+--------+------------+---------+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|  90120 |      57095 | 7077017 | ACT   | MST      | PAA       | 021456668 |
+--------+------------+---------+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```